# sqlmlutils: Process data using python and then update records accordingly without leaving database

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I want to process an SQL (MSSQL) table using python (pandas/natural language processing). After getting a per-record result, I would like to store the result in the same table, in an existing (empty) column.

Because the table is quite large (>10m records) I am trying to figure out how to do this without having the data leave that database. Is it possible to achieve this using the python add-in to MSSQL?

I have set up sqlmlutils and the required packages for my script. However, I cannot figure out how to process *and* store the results without the data leaving the database.

EDIT

To clarify what I am trying to do:

I have a table `dbo.table` containing over 10 million rows and a particular text column, say `col`.
Using python and language processing, I want to process the contents of `col` to obtain a new value and store the result in `col2`, again of table `dbo.table`.

Because this is so much data, I would like to cut out the time to transfer the data to my pc, and transferring back the result.

So my question is in two-fold: can I achieve this using the SQL-Server extension `sqlmlutils`? And if not, would there be a feasible alternative?

Comment: what is it you want to do ?  and by not leaving database , do you mean do whatever it is using sql in database engine? you have to explain what are you trying to do with your data

Comment: @eshirvana I added some specification